# How to use CSS absolute position inside a scrollable div element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have the following HTML content. I have multiple elements (e.g., *div* with id = one, two, three) inside a *div* container which is scrollable.

In each element, I need to use CSS position 'absolute' which position related to its parent *div* (i.e., *class='Anchor'*).

The problem I am having is, when I scroll the outer container, none of the *div*s with an absolute position moved. My understanding of position 'absolute' is it is positioned relative to its parent DIV element. How can I make those 'absolute' position move as I scroll the outer container?

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll">
   <div>
      <div class="Anchor" id="one">
           <div style="position: absolute"> something </div>
           <div style="position: absolute"> something else </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="Anchor" id="two">
           <div style="position: absolute"> something </div>
           <div style="position: absolute"> something else </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="Anchor" id="three">
           <div style="position: absolute"> something </div>
           <div style="position: absolute"> something else </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the parent div or divs to `position: relative;` and the child divs that are `position: absolute;` will be placed *relative* to the position of their parent elements.

Comment: Like @TylerH said, You have to specify `position: relative` on the parent that you want them to anchor to. Absolutely positioned elements will be positioned relative to the nearest relatively positioned parent, but `div` elements have `position: static` by default.

Comment: The HTML content is invalid. There are 13 `<div>`s and 9 `</div>`s. A validator, like the [W3 one](https://validator.w3.org/nu/), can check it. [The result](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2FSO_37471396_wrapped.html) (when wrapped in an HTML document to reduce spurious errors) is ***"Error: End tag for body seen, but there were unclosed elements."*** and four times ***"Unclosed element div."*** (the former is a result of the latter).

Comment: [The result without wrapping](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fpmortensen.eu%2Ftemp2%2FSO_37471396.html). It includes the five error results.

Comment: (A moderation action on this question is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418973/how-to-handle-low-reputation-users-editing-highly-voted-posts-high-reputation).)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must set `position: relative;` on the parent div to get the child elements to move in relation to it.

The reality is, you can have the parent div set to any user-defined position, as long as the default `static` position isn't being used.

Comment: that is great. Do you happen to know how to do the opposite.. its crazy but i have a relative parent with height set and scrollable contents...one child element is absolute but when scrolling ..it goes with  the contents as if it was realtive to that.. but its not... its a direct sibling of the scrollable contents

Comment: @carinlynchin you need to add another div with position relative on top of scrollable div. don't mix position relative and overflow.

Answer (score 5):

Try `position: sticky` on the *div* that you want to make float. Also beware the [browser support is not that great for sticky](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).